# Close a partially fulfilled work order via SuiteTalk API?

Tags: c#, web-services, netsuite

I was wondering if it is possible to "close" a work order using the SuiteTalk API in a way that would be equivalent to clicking the "Close" button in the NetSuite UI?

I can get the status to switch to "Built" by changing the Work Order quantity to match the currently built amount, but this is not really what I'm looking for as I'd rather not have to store the differences in a separate table.

I have also tried setting orderStatus (with orderStatusSpecified set to true) manually, but NetSuite does not seem to 'like' this, and automatically reverts the status.

Any suggestions here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking on the close button on the UI means that you are setting the close line item column to true.  Try looping thru all the line items of the transaction and setting the "close" column to "T".  If I recall correctly the field is for the "close" column is "isclosed".